# Publishing Geoprocessing Service with importing of numpy in ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, numpy, geoprocessing-service

I use a lot of scripts as GP Service almost all use the arcpy functions but one (and very important) of my scripts needs a gdal/ogr and numpy imports. I can run this script in PyScripter or as a tool in Toolbox in ArcMap. Now, I am trying to publish my script from GP Result window as GP Service on ArcGIS Server 10.1. This is weird because I can see only Packaging in progress window a long time and after 30 minutes I must kill the Service Editor. 
I tested my script by commenting it line by line and publishing each time as a GP service. I have already found the reason of my problems but still I do not have solution.  The publishing problems appear when I use import of numpy  in my script (import numpy as np or import numpy). Does anyone know the reason of this state? Numpy is very important library so I think the solution should exists.

---

I have tested my simple script

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo.gdalconst import *
import numpy as np

arcpy.AddMessage("End")
print("End")
```

It runs in ArcGIS for Desktop but I can not publish service. I always get window Packing in progress

[image]

When I comment out `import as np` I can publish service successfully.

Comment: Give a quick read of this topic: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Authoring_geoprocessing_tasks_with_Python_scripts/00570000007r000000/  If it takes forever to publish its either a) stuck in a bad loop, or more likely b) trying to copy/consolidate a larger amount of data over. From the above link, make sure you dont have pointers at folders with a lot of data inside (unless you need that)

Comment: I'm guessing its a typo in the question, but shouldn't "import Numpy" be "import numpy" lowercase?

Comment: I am sorry for distracting typo, I use numpy in my script.

Comment: One more quick test: Goto Customize >ArcMap Options > Sharing Tab. Note the "Staging Path". When in seems stuck, go there, find the folder its generating and look inside. Is there a lot of content being copied in? And do you have 10.1 sp1 installed?

Comment: Strange thing happened. When I have changed the method of importing inside my script from import numpy to from numpy import * I published my service successfully. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

The asker (@ConeGIS) has indicated in a Comment that this went away when:

```
  import numpy
```

was replaced by:

```
  from numpy import *
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you check and make sure that the 64bit version of numpy is also installed on the server machine.  I believe that 10.1 Desktop uses 32bit Python and Server uses 64bit.  If numpy isn't install on 64bit that could be the issue.

Comment: Not really related, it's hanging in the packaging stage. Also, if you have correctly installed any 64 bit ArcGIS product it will already include the 64 bit numpy.

Comment: good point, possibly a later issue with ogr/gdal but not during the packaging phase.

Comment: On my server machine I have got numpy forArcGIS for Desktop (C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages) and server (C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1\Lib\site-packages\numpy)