# Broken Project Data Source

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, geoprocessing

I have built a Script Tool (from a modelbuilder model) in ArcGIS 10.2 which works perfectly fine in ArcGIS.

However, I am getting the following error message when I try to publish this script tool into a geoprocessing service on ArcGIS Server.

I am using in_memory workspace for outputs. Not sure if that is causing the problem.

**Error Message -**

[image]
**Code Sample** -

```
> # 5 & 6 - District Query & Final Query
>     if District == "Citywide":
>         gp.AddMessage (("Selected Citywide Stolen Autos..." ))
>         Final_Query = Query + Select_the_Date_Range + " AND " + SQL_Query_Refining_the_Data
> 
>     else:
>         Select_the_District = "(DC_DISTRICT = " + District + ")"
>         Final_Query = Query + Select_the_Date_Range + " AND " +  Select_the_District + " AND " + SQL_Query_Refining_the_Data
> 
>     arcpy.env.workspace = r"in_memory"
>     gp.AddMessage("")
>     gp.AddMessage("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
>     gp.AddMessage (("Querying the PIIN table for dates from " + Date_FROM + " to " + Date_TO + " & District = " + District ))
> 
>     # Process 1 : Querying the PIIN Table and exporting the selection to a in memory FC
>     arcpy.MakeQueryLayer_management(InputDatabase, "StolenRec_ActiveStol_FC", Final_Query)
>     arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("StolenRec_ActiveStol_FC", StolenRec_ActiveStol_FC_3)
> 
> 
>     gp.AddMessage (("Making XY Event Layer from Recovered Location..." ))
>     # Process 2: Making XY Event Layer
>     arcpy.TableToTable_conversion("StolenRec_ActiveStol_FC", "in_memory" , "StolenRec_ActiveStol_FC_2", "")
>     arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management("StolenRec_ActiveStol_FC_2", "RECOVERED_X_COORD", "RECOVERED_Y_COORD", "Recovered_ELayer",
> "PROJCS['NAD_1983_StatePlane_Pennsylvania_South_FIPS_3702_Feet',GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1983',DATUM['D_North_American_1983',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Lambert_Conformal_Conic'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',1968500.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',-77.75],PARAMETER['Standard_Parallel_1',39.93333333333333],PARAMETER['Standard_Parallel_2',40.96666666666667],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',39.33333333333334],UNIT['Foot_US',0.3048006096012192]];-119214200
> -96198500 3048.00609601219;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;3.28083333333333E-03;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision", "")
> 
>     gp.AddMessage (("Converting XY Event Layer to FC..." ))
>     # Process 3: Converting XY Event Layer to a in memory Point Feature Class
>     #arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(Recovered_ELayer, in_memory, "Recovered_FC_Layer","")
>     arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("Recovered_ELayer", Recovered_FC_Layer_2)
```

Comment: Do the tables, layers, and feature classes exist/what are their names? Insert a few `arcpy.Exists()` and print statements.

Comment: Try changing your  arcpy.TableToTable_conversion to arcpy.CopyRows(). Not sure I see the real need for T2T or CRs, but the error states it cant find _StolenRec_ActiveStol_FC_2_ which comes from T2T and going into MakeXY.

Comment: Also, if that doesn't solve it (I see _StolenRec_ActiveStol_FC_ in that list as well), be **explicit**, not implicit. That is use full in_memory paths to items `("in_memory/StolenRec_ActiveStol_FC_3")`, don't rely on the arcpy.env.workspace to build the path on your behalf.

Comment: @Paul &@KHibma Thanks for responding. The CopyRows() & being explicit seem to did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem last week and it was fixed by changing

```
import module
```

to

```
from module import name
```

See [Publishing Geoprocessing Service with importing of numpy in ArcGIS Server?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75138) and [GeoNet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/158172) for more details.

Just another one of those interesting quirks of publishing to server :-/